# Talk to PC from ROSJava/Android using USB?

Tags: usb, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to connect a Android Phone using ROSJava and a PC running the ROS Core via USB? I'm hoping to not use Wifi. Or alternatively, has anyone seen any projects that attempted this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33661/talk-to-pc-from-rosjava/android-using-usb?/) by [zmoratto](https://answers.ros.org/users/1543/zmoratto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zmoratto](https://answers.ros.org/users/1543/zmoratto/) on 2012-05-11**:
Follow up, if your phone supports tethering this appears to be really easy. My phone was locked down by Verizon. However using a custom ROM was an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is possible if your phone supports USB tethering.  [See my question here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10235/android-and-ros-communication-over-usb-instead-of).

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3